# Is there a way to build a StAX filter chain?

Tags: java, xml, filter, sax, stax

Making custom transformations for different event types with **StAX** using `EventFilter` and `StreamFilter` I feel being forced into a procedural implementation - extract these events and process them, filter those events and process them, than put all the results back together and return.
**SAX** seems to have a really nice feature there - chainable filters based on [XMLFilters](http://sax.sourceforge.net/apidoc/org/xml/sax/XMLFilter.html). 
 I would prefer to keep my implementation StAX-based, but to somehow incorporate or emulate the chainable filters from SAX.
Can this be done with a reasonable effort and how? Is there an implementation already that I have missed?
Due to project limitations I have to stick to the JDK, so please do not suggest using a different library as an answer, but feel free to suggest one in the comments - I'd love to know what`s out there.

Comment: I am not working on the project anymore, but I have discovered vtd-xml back then and have argued for its adoption. The tech lead pushed for a minimal, JDK-only stack however, so unfortunately we didnt get to play with vtd much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`EventReaderDelegate`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/util/EventReaderDelegate.html) and [`StreamReaderDelegate`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/util/StreamReaderDelegate.html). These classes will allow you to wrap a parent event or stream reader so that you can interpose whatever logic you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use delegates, I think one of very few areas where SAX has edge over Stax is ability to construct efficients modular pipelines. Stax is more optimal for recursive-descent approaches, as well as partial data binding (can traverse stream; hand chunks to JAXB, continue, very simple, powerful).

Comment: Re "can traverse stream; hand chunks to JAXB, continue"... are there good examples of this somewhere besides in the Metro impl jar?

Comment: I wish I had links (I did do an xml presentation that had snippets, but that's not a public one alas). But basic idea is quite simple; create an XMLStreamReader, traverse it, pass to JAXB Unmarshaller for binding (making sure it points to START_ELEMENT; after binding will be over matching END_ELEMENT).