# What is the best way to modify a few fields in an XML using Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xslt, xpath

I have a big XML which contains around 300 elements. I need to modify 2 or 3 elements in this xml using Java. I don't want to go for conventional marshalling and unmarshalling as it involves the parsing of the whole XML. How is XPath/XSLT manipulation? I know that I can easily read the data but i need to modify the same and put in back in the same XML. The primary concern here is performance. Kindly advise

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath/XSLT means that you load the whole document into memory before you start to transform it. If that is a problem (e.g. document too big for memory), then you need to use another solution. That said, 300 elements doesn't sound very "big".

One alternative would be to use a StAX parser to find and change the target elements. Take a look at [Is there a way to build a StAX filter chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5566836/127035)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like XSLT might be too heavyweight for this problem.  You want to rewrite a file slightly.  If you can describe each change easily (for example, you want to remove the "foo" attribute on the "bar" element), consider applying a regular expression substitution.  Something like this:

`String fileContents = ...`

`fileContents.replaceAll("<bar foo=\"\\w+\"", "<bar");`